# VueJS: this.$refs is undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Vue 2.5.16 and bootstrap-vue 2.0.0 rc.11 in a Laravel 5 project. As part of one vue-file I'm opening a modal like this:

```
<button v-b-modal.modalSettings>Settings</button>
```

The modal is defined and this works when I compile the file using "npm run dev" or "npm run watch". When I'm compiling the project using "npm run prod" the modal isn't opening, without any error message.

To debug this I've tried to run

```
this.$refs.modalSettings.show();
```

on the console as well as part of the code. Both times I get

```
TypeError: this.$refs is undefined
```

I've tried Google for more information. All solutions were for non-completely loaded apps - which isn't applying to my case as far as I can tell. Any got any ideas what to look at?

Comment: How do you test the build version? In a local server. Also where did you call the this.$refs.modalSettings.show(); In a method ?

Comment: Hey @keysl thanks for responding. I've first noticed the issue on a beta version I gave someone to test. Then I replicated the same locally with the built-in Laravel server (php artisan serve). The only difference seems to be "dev" vs. "prod". I've tried v-on:click="this.$refs.modalSettings.show();" to see if the issue is the same.

Comment: You don't use the `this` prefix in template expressions so it should be `v-on:click=$refs.modalSettings.show()"`

Comment: Hey @Phil, thanks for responding. I've tried it without "this" and didn't work either. Same behavior. Any other ideas?